# Pipe encrypted archive to uploader

Tags: bash, pipe, function

Assume, I do archive several files with this functions:

```
gen_password () 
{
    gpg --gen-random 1 "$1" | perl -ne'
        s/[\x00-\x20]/chr(ord($^N)+50)/ge;
        s/([\x7E-\xDB])/chr(ord($^N)-93)/ge;
        s/([\xDC-\xFF])/chr(ord($^N)-129)/ge;
        print $_, "\n"'
}

archive () 
{
    ARCHIVE_NAME="$1"
    PASSWORD=$(gen_password 32)
    7za a -p"$PASSWORD" -mhe -- "$ARCHIVE_NAME" "$@"
    echo "Created 7z archive with password '$PASSWORD'"
}
```

This works well and I tried to upload encrypted archive on [file sharing server](https://transfer.sh/).

So there is the script that uploads content of file to the server([source](https://gist.github.com/nl5887/a511f172d3fb3cd0e42d)):

```
upload() 
{
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then echo "No arguments specified. Usage:\necho transfer /tmp/test.md\ncat /tmp/test.md | transfer test.md"; return 1; fi 
    tmpfile=$( mktemp -t transferXXX ); if tty -s; then basefile=$(basename "$1" | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/-/g'); curl --progress-bar --upload-file "$1" "https://transfer.sh/$basefile" >> $tmpfile; else curl --progress-bar --upload-file "-" "https://transfer.sh/$1" >> $tmpfile ; fi; cat $tmpfile; rm -f $tmpfile;
}
```

So I'm trying to pipe the encrypted archive in naive way:

```
archive 1.rar pass.tar.gz d7432.png foo.7z | upload
```

But there is one problem - encrypted archive is unreacheable for `upload` and command exiting with no result.

So, the question is: how should I pipe the file to have it uploaded correctly?

Comment: it appears to me that your archive function is creating a filename (1.rar for example) and echos a string "Created 7z..."; that echoed string is the only thing that `upload` will see on its stdin. Maybe something like `archive 1.rar ... && upload 1.rar` ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller seems like you're right. Is it possible to somehow pipe only name of resultiong `foo.7z` to `upload` function without deleting `echo`?

Comment: `echo other stuff >&2; echo foo.7z`

Comment: @JeffSchaller unfortunately, still getting same result as initially. Seems like this functions could not be modularized(_well, at least with my shell scripting skills_) and I should consider `upload` handle the encryption too

Comment: well, upload() is getting stdin from your pipeline, but it seems to be expecting a parameter; either pass it a parameter or have it read the filename from stdin

Comment: if we've answered your question, please don't forget to accept it with the checkmark; thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your upload() function is expecting a parameter ($1) to use as the archived filename, pass it along in your commandline:

```
archive foo.7z 1.rar pass.tar.gz d7432.png && upload foo.7z
```

If foo.7z is a variable parameter for archive() as well, simply pass the same variable to upload():

```
archive $archivename 1.rar pass.tar.gz d7432.png && upload $archivename
```

I would recommend the `&&` glue, as you probably don't want to try to upload the archive file if the archive() function did not succeed.

Here is sample function for `.bashrc`:

```
share()
{
    ARCHIVE_NAME="$1"
    archive "$ARCHIVE_NAME" "$@" && upload "$ARCHIVE_NAME"
}
```

Comment: Seems like this works! Thanks a lot for your time!